# Change seek bar value when changing volume

Tags: android, volume, seekbar

I have this seek bar that when I enter the app it takes the value of the phone's volume (if the volume is to the max, the seek bar is full and so on).
When I change seek bar value the phone's volume changes (as it should).

But my problem is how to change the seek bar's value when I change the phone's volume through the volume up and volume down buttons in the device

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_media_player);
    initializeUIElements();
    initializeMediaPlayer();
}



 private void initializeUIElements() {

    sbPlay = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.sbPlay);
    sbPlay.setMax(100);
    sbPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    btPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btPlay);
    btPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    btStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btStop);
    btStop.setEnabled(false);
    btStop.setOnClickListener(this);

    sbVolume = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbVolume);
    try {
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        sbVolume.setMax(audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        sbVolume.setProgress(audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));


        sbVolume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        progress, 0);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVEDDD

```
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) 
{ 
       int index = seekbar.getProgress(); 
       seekbar.setProgress(index + 1); 
       return true; 
} else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
 {
       int index = seekbar.getProgress(); 
       seekbar.setProgress(index - 1); 
       return true; 
}
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
}
```